# Adding Text before Formula that returns a number

Tags: formula, formula-field

I've developed a formula that will convert a date field into the week number.See code below.

```
CEILING(((  Trial_Account_Date_Created__c  - DATE(YEAR(Trial_Account_Date_Created__c  ), 1, 1) + 1) + 
MOD(DATE(YEAR(Trial_Account_Date_Created__c  ), 1, 1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)) / 7)
```

Now what I want to do is to add the text "Week" before the number in the formula. I tried many things but I got stuck.

Please advise,

Darko

Comment: What is your formula return type?

Comment: The formula return type is number.

Comment: Try my answer and let me know if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below after making the formula return type as "Text",

```
'Week' + Text(CEILING(((  BirthDate- DATE(YEAR(BirthDate), 1, 1) + 1) + 
MOD(DATE(YEAR(BirthDate), 1, 1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)) / 7))
```

Comment: I already tried that :(
Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number

Comment: Hey i have updated. and it works for me.

Comment: Works like a charm. Now i just got a  problem with the report to show from Week 1 till Week 52 tried everything seems not working but thats other subject.

Thanks you allot for the help :)

Comment: You can think of adding a new question for your above query. I might answer that one too ;)

Comment: Here is the link to the question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71034/chart-to-show-ascending-formula-values

Answer (score -1):

```
=`"wk"&WEEKNUM(select the cell has the day)`
```

example:
wk25
06/14/15