# Chart to show Ascending formula values

Tags: reporting, formula, charts

I am not able to make the report show values ascending from Week 1 to Week 52.This is formula that i use from the backend and also an adding to my previous question.
[Adding Text before Formula that returns a number](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71024/adding-text-before-formula-that-returns-a-number/71025?noredirect=1#comment92725_71025)

I want the weeks to be shown in from Week 1 till Week 52 and not like this.
[image]

I tried to group them in the report but no luck.

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify formula field so that it puts a "0" in front of weeks < 10. Then the ordering should work.

Add 1 more formula field that can calculate the previous field adding the following:

```
IF( Week_number_Trial_Account__c < 10, 'Week ' + '0' +  TEXT(Week_number_Trial_Account__c) , 'Week ' + TEXT(Week_number_Trial_Account__c))
```

Comment: Hi @Uwe can you please elaborate more on this? I am confused :( Thanks,

Comment: I think what @Uwe was trying to get to is to have the first 9 weeks calculate as Week 01, Week 02, Week 03, etc... so that they will end up in correct numerical order.

Comment: Yes sfdc_nerd that is exactly what i did :) I just needed time to figure that out :D